# using a bash array as arguments to a script?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to build up an array and then use it as the arguments to a script. When I echo out the command I think I'm building, it looks fine. But when I try to execute it, nothing happens. Here's a small example. In my actual script, I have to build the array at run time so I can't hard code `(/tmp -iname "*.log*")` And it has to run in older bash environments too, so I can't use `+=` to append to an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=( /tmp )
args[${#args[@]}]=-iname
args[${#args[@]}]="\"*.log\""

# the following echoes what I expect: find /tmp -iname "*.log"
echo find "${args[@]}"

# this next line does not appear to find any files
find "${args[@]}"

echo the following finds files 
find /tmp -iname "*.log"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you used `set -x` (or `bash -x yourscript`) and compared output between your script in that mode and running the command you want by hand, the issue would have been obvious.

Comment: (Short form: **syntactic** quotes are resolved early in the parsing process, _before_ parameter expansion happens, so putting quotes inside of a piece of data, those quotes stay data when they're expanded and never become syntax).

Comment: ...instead of `echo "${foo[@]}"`, by the way, you might consider getting in the habit of `printf '%q ' "${foo[@]}"; echo`.

Comment: `echo "${foo[@]}"` is pretty much useless, because `echo` doesn't show you the difference between `echo "hello world"` and `echo "hello" "world"`, so it gives you no idea whatsoever as to whether or not you have quoting problems in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quotes inside quotes, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=( /tmp )
args[${#args[@]}]=-iname
args[${#args[@]}]='*.log'

find "${args[@]}"
```